# Issues prestashop template css edge or IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, prestashop, microsoft-edge, prestashop-1.7

I have an issue on my Prestashop website my css code is not reading on Edge or IE, but its working on Chrome/Safari/Opera

My prestashop version is 1.7.6.0

This is my URL: https://www.herboristerie.com/

I put different meta on my head, but it's not working

This is my code :

```html
{block name='head_ie_compatibility'}
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">   
    <!--[if IE]>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.herboristerie.com/themes/bos_nature/assets/css/theme.css" type="text/css" media="all">

  <![endif]-->
{/block}
```

Do you knpw why my css is not working ?

Thanks !

Comment: Run devTools in chrome and see how many bugs there are. Fix them to fix the look in IE/Edge

Comment: Whether you are using the theme or CSS library on your website? Please check whether they are support IE and Edge browser. Besides, I have tried to use F12 developer NetWork tools to check the "https://www.herboristerie.com/themes/bos_nature/assets/css/theme.css" file, it seems that the response body doesn't contain the related CSS styles for the navbar, you could check [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ene9I.png).